# Not able to write or send data to BLE hardware using react-native ble-manager[ write error status-3]

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native, react-native-ios

I am able to make a BLE connection with the hardware. By using service UUID and characteristics UUID I am able to receive data from the hardware through start notification function. But when I try to send data to the hardware its showing error [Write error status-3] as shown in the below code.

```
BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheral.id).then((peripheralInfo) => {
              console.log(peripheralInfo);

              var service = '6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e';
              var WriteCharacteristic = '6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e';
              var ReadCharacteristic = '6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e';

              setTimeout(() => {

                // receiving data from hardware 
                BleManager.startNotification(peripheral.id, service, ReadCharacteristic).then(() => {
                  console.log('Started notification on ' + peripheral.id);
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      // sending data to the hardware
                    BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, WriteCharacteristic, [1,95]).then(() => {
                      console.log('Writed NORMAL crust');
                    });

                  }, 500);
                }).catch((error) => {
                  console.log('Notification error', error);
                });
```

First faced some problems with characteristics not found. After some changes, I am getting error as

```
Write error Status - 3
```

I am not able to find any solution for this error.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

While using BleManager.write, you should first prepare your data

Data preparation:

If your data is not in byte array format you should convert it first. For strings you can use convert-string or other npm package in order to achieve that. Install the package first:

```
npm install convert-string
```

Then use it in your application:

```
// Import/require in the beginning of the file
import { stringToBytes } from "convert-string";
// Convert data to byte array before write/writeWithoutResponse
const data = stringToBytes(yourStringData);
```

In my case I converted my data to byte format, this way and you can do the same.

```
const dataByte = convertString.UTF8.stringToBytes(data);
```

Then used in my code

```
BleManager.retrieveServices(currentDevice.PID).then((peripheralInfo) => {
      console.log(peripheralInfo);
      BleManager.write(
        currentDevice.PID,
        '0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
        dataByte,
      )
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Sent ${dataByte}`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  };
```