# Error when using write() with "react-native-ble-manager" library with status=3

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-ble-plx, react-native-ble-manager

So, I'm trying to send data to BLE device.
My phone and BLE device are already connected.

My function:

```js
  const sendCom = async () => {
    const data = utf8Encode('1') // convert data to bytes
    const service = 'fff0'
    const characteristic = 'fff1'
    try {
      await BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheral.id)
      await BleManager.startNotification(peripheral.id, service,              characteristic)
      await BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, characteristic, data)
      console.log(`Sent: ${data}`)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error writing ${characteristic}: ${error}`)
    }
  }
```

`peripheral` object:

```
{"advertising": {"isConnectable": true, "localName": "BLE-Waveshare",
 "manufacturerData": {"CDVType": "ArrayBuffer",
 "bytes": [Array],
 "data": "AgEGAwPw/w4JQkxFLVdhdmVzaGFyZQf/mRSchH35AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="},
 "serviceData": {}, "serviceUUIDs": ["fff0"],
 "txPowerLevel": -2147483648},
 "characteristics": [{"characteristic": "fff1", "descriptors": [Array],
 "properties": [Object], "service": "fff0"},
 {"characteristic": "fff2", "descriptors": [Array],
  "properties": [Object], "service": "fff0"}
, {"characteristic": "fff3", "properties": [Object],
 "service": "fff0"}], "id": "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
 "name": "BLE-Waveshare", "rssi": -41,
 "services": [{"uuid": "fff0"}]}
```

I'm calling this function by `onPress` prop in `Pressable` component. Error occurs only when I trying to `write()` something.

I tried to find answer on the internet, but didn't find.
I also tried this function in different variations for example using Promises with  `.then()` and  `.catch()`, like so:

```js
    const sendCom = async () => {
      const data = utf8Encode('1') // convert data to bytes
      const service = 'fff0'
      const characteristic = 'fff1'
      BleManager.retrieveServices(peripheral.id)
        .then(() => {
          BleManager.startNotification(peripheral.id, service, characteristic)
        })
        .then(() => {
          BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, characteristic, data)
          console.log(`Sent: ${data}`)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error writing ${characteristic}: ${error}`)
        })
    }
```

The error I getting:

`Error writing fff1: Error writing 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb status=3`

It will be nice if you explain what `status 3` means.

[Similar question with same error but no relevant answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130904/not-able-to-write-or-send-data-to-ble-hardware-using-react-native-ble-manager-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use writeWithoutResponse() insted of write() and it worked as I expected. So if you have similar issue you can try same thing.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your question! Elaborating on why `write` works and `writeWithoutResponse` does not may be helpful for future readers.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know myself. I'm not expert in that, so there is a huge chance that I will be wrong with explanation